# Android database files not being created

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

The file for the database is not being created I've checked under data->data->->(where the database I expect to be). I can't tell if there is an issue with the code or the application itself. I think a second set of eyes could help.

**DatabaseHelper.class**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "prevGames";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE playerRecords ("
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "DATE TEXT, "
                + "NAME TEXT, "
                + "TOTAL INTEGER);"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "playerRecords");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertRecord(String date, String name, int total)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues recordValues = new ContentValues();
        recordValues.put("DATE", date);
        recordValues.put("NAME", name);
        recordValues.put("TOTAL", total);
        long newRecordID = db.insert("playerRecords", null, recordValues);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** - After more testing, I think my problem is related to the button assigned using the insertRecords method. The following code is one of my activities called gamePage. But I'm unsure how to fix the issue with my button as I've tested it and it doesn't proceed to the next activity either and I'm certain the code is right and the manifest has been updated appropriately.

```
import static android.view.View.GONE;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class gamePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText player1Score1, player1Score2, player1Score3;
    private EditText player2Score1,  player2Score2, player2Score3;
    private EditText player3Score1, player3Score2, player3Score3;
    private EditText player4Score1,  player4Score2, player4Score3;
    private TextView total1, total2, total3, total4;
    private Button submit;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_page);

        String date_n = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        TextView date  = findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(date_n);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        TableRow player1Data = findViewById(R.id.player1Data);
        TableRow player2Data = findViewById(R.id.player2Data);
        TableRow player3Data = findViewById(R.id.player3Data);
        TableRow player4Data = findViewById(R.id.player4Data);

        total1 = findViewById(R.id.total1);
        total2 = findViewById(R.id.total2);
        total3 = findViewById(R.id.total3);
        total4 = findViewById(R.id.total4);

        player1Score1 = findViewById(R.id.p1Score1);
        player1Score2 = findViewById(R.id.p1Score2);
        player1Score3 = findViewById(R.id.p1Score3);

        player2Score1 = findViewById(R.id.p2Score1);
        player2Score2 = findViewById(R.id.p2Score2);
        player2Score3 = findViewById(R.id.p2Score3);

        player3Score1 = findViewById(R.id.p3Score1);
        player3Score2 = findViewById(R.id.p3Score2);
        player3Score3 = findViewById(R.id.p3Score3);

        player4Score1 = findViewById(R.id.p4Score1);
        player4Score2 = findViewById(R.id.p4Score2);
        player4Score3 = findViewById(R.id.p4Score3);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String p1Input = intent.getStringExtra("P1");
        String p2Input = intent.getStringExtra("P2");
        String p3Input = intent.getStringExtra("P3");
        String p4Input = intent.getStringExtra("P4");

        TextView player1Input = findViewById(R.id.name1);
        TextView player2Input = findViewById(R.id.name2);
        TextView player3Input = findViewById(R.id.name3);
        TextView player4Input = findViewById(R.id.name4);

// Check if the enter name values are empty if so deletes the row if not updates the text
        if (p1Input != null && !p1Input.isEmpty()) {
            player1Input.setText(p1Input);
        } else {
            player1Data.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        if (p2Input != null && !p2Input.isEmpty()) {
            player2Input.setText(p2Input);
        } else {
            player2Data.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        if (p3Input != null && !p3Input.isEmpty()) {
            player3Input.setText(p3Input);
        } else {
            player3Data.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        if (p4Input != null && !p4Input.isEmpty()) {
            player4Input.setText(p4Input);
        } else {
            player4Data.setVisibility(GONE);
        }


// End of the if check
//
//
//
// Start of text Listeners for scores
        player1Score1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player1Score2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player1Score3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});

        player2Score1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player2Score2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player2Score3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});

        player3Score1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player3Score2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player3Score3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});

        player4Score1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player4Score2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
        player4Score3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....});
// End of text listeners
//
//
// Submit buttons for inserting data into the database and taking to end of game screen
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(gamePage.this);
                //Get the data to be inserted
                String name1 = player1Input.getText().toString();
                int p1total1 = Integer.parseInt(total1.getText().toString());

                String name2 = player2Input.getText().toString();
                int p2total2 = Integer.parseInt(total2.getText().toString());

                String name3 = player3Input.getText().toString();
                int p3total3 = Integer.parseInt(total3.getText().toString());

                String name4 = player4Input.getText().toString();
                int p4total4 = Integer.parseInt(total4.getText().toString());

                //Add the data to the database
                dbHelper.insertRecord(date_n, name1, p1total1);
                dbHelper.insertRecord(date_n, name2, p2total2);
                dbHelper.insertRecord(date_n, name3, p3total3);
                dbHelper.insertRecord(date_n, name4, p4total4);
                Intent End = new Intent(gamePage.this,gameEndPage.class);
                startActivity(End);
            }
        });

    }

    //Method for updating the total by collecting the score from text fields
    private void updateTotal() {
        int p1score1 = 0, p1score2 = 0, p1score3 = 0;
        int p2score1 = 0, p2score2 = 0, p2score3 = 0;
        int p3score1 = 0, p3score2 = 0, p3score3 = 0;
        int p4score1 = 0, p4score2 = 0, p4score3 = 0;
        //player 1 score entry
        if (!player1Score1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p1score1 = Integer.parseInt(player1Score1.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player1Score2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p1score2 = Integer.parseInt(player1Score2.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player1Score3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p1score3 = Integer.parseInt(player1Score3.getText().toString());
        }
        //player 2 score entry
        if (!player2Score1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p2score1 = Integer.parseInt(player2Score1.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player2Score2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p2score2 = Integer.parseInt(player2Score2.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player2Score3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p2score3 = Integer.parseInt(player2Score3.getText().toString());
        }
        //player 3 score entry
        if (!player3Score1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p3score1 = Integer.parseInt(player3Score1.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player3Score2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p3score2 = Integer.parseInt(player3Score2.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player3Score3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p3score3 = Integer.parseInt(player3Score3.getText().toString());
        }
        //player 4 score entry
        if (!player4Score1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p4score1 = Integer.parseInt(player4Score1.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player4Score2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p4score2 = Integer.parseInt(player4Score2.getText().toString());
        }
        if (!player4Score3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            p4score3 = Integer.parseInt(player4Score3.getText().toString());
        }
        int p1total = p1score1 + p1score2 + p1score3;
        int p2total = p2score1 + p2score2 + p2score3;
        int p3total = p3score1 + p3score2 + p3score3;
        int p4total = p4score1 + p4score2 + p4score3;
        total1.setText(String.valueOf(p1total));
        total2.setText(String.valueOf(p2total));
        total3.setText(String.valueOf(p3total));
        total4.setText(String.valueOf(p4total));
    }
    // End of method



}
```

Comment: `I've checked under data->data->` Please tell how you did that.

Comment: Under Device Explorer for the selected device, I'm running the application. Then proceeded to go through the folders as mentioned above until I reached my package where the database should've been located.

Comment: You should mention full path of directory where you expect your database files as now its useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DatabaseHelper class appears to define the structure and handling of a SQLite database, including table creation and an insertRecord method. However, the issue might lie in how the class is being used or instantiated within your application.

Here are a few points to consider:

Note: I recommend (Logging) the database creation events if they are fired or not.

Context Initialization: Ensure that you initialize the DatabaseHelper class with the appropriate context. You currently have a static context variable but it's not being used for anything within this class. Ensure that the Context passed to the DatabaseHelper constructor is the application's context.

Database Creation: The onCreate method should be called when the database is first created. It seems that the onCreate method is responsible for creating the "playerRecords" table. Make sure that you're calling getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() somewhere in your application code to trigger the creation of the database if it doesn't exist.

Database Usage: After creating an instance of DatabaseHelper, use the insertRecord method to insert data into the database. Ensure that you call this method after properly instantiating DatabaseHelper within your application.

Error Handling: Check for any logs or exceptions that might be generated during the database creation or data insertion process. Logging errors or exceptions can help identify issues.

Database Location: The database file might be created in a different location on certain devices or due to specific configurations. You can also check for any errors in logs related to database creation or file access.

Make sure you're following these steps and that the insertRecord method is being called properly with the correct data. Additionally, check logs or debugging outputs for any exceptions or errors related to the database handling.

**EDIT**
If your code seems to be right and the submit_button is not clicking or fireing you may consider checking the layout xml of the activity you're using for any focusable or clickable values

e.g
make sure you remove

```
<!-- set it to true or remove it if it exists -->
android:clickable="true/false"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and tip. I went back to check on some of the things you mentioned with further testing I found the issue may be from submit_btn. If possible could you have a look at my updated edit with additional code linked to the certain activity that is using the button to create the records?

Comment: Sure no problem.

Comment: The button didn't have anything related to focusable or clickable values I went to recreate it. I've now found out that my app is not being updated on the device and still running an old version of the project. Currently, I'm searching around for a fix but if you've got any clue on how to fix it I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Update: Fixed the issue for some odd reason I have to manually recompile my activity for it to update at least now it works !!